# Java-like stepping out of a bash function when tracing it

Tags: bash, debugging, trace

While tracing a function in `bash`, I can return non-zero value (say,`1`) from by `DEBUG` `trap` handler to skip the execution of the next line.

Also, I can return the value `2` to execute a `return` statement to return out of the function without executing the rest of the function body

However, I would like to be able to **step out** of the current function, not by `return'ing, but by executing the remainder of the function body in just a single shot (instead of executing it line-by-line till the end of its body).

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tedious sure, but it seems this can be done with the existing callstack information provided by Bash.

Here's how.

Keep executing your `DEBUG` trap handler till you reach the next callstack frame, F2, sitting right under the current one, F1, and stop on a line number that is greater than or equal to the `BASH_LINENO` saved in F2. The *'... or equal to'* check is required to address recursive calls.